# align-self on child vertically not working on a display flex column parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i am new to flex and i have 2 child, 1 i want to center and 1 on bottom:

```
<div className="parent">
  <div className="main">center me</div>
  <div className="footer">put me on bottom</div>
<div>
```

this is my style:

```
.parent { 
  width:100%;
  display:flex
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
}
.main {
  align-self: center;
}
.footer {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

the classes main and footer is not working as i expected? help?

Comment: note that you are missing `;` at the end of `display:flex`

Comment: so i didn't know margin works for this stuffs easily